Workflow Settings tab in Lighting's window is missing since version 2023 in Unity
I've just noticed that the Workflow Settings tab is missing in Unity editor versions 2023+. How are developers suppose to update the environment automatically with the tab missing?
In the 2022 version, when the option is checked, the Unity automatically recalculates the environment based on the light (in cases of day and night cycles). In 2023 there's no option for that and with nothing touched in the Lighting window, the environment light simply doesn't change.
2022 version:

2023 version:

The only thing I came up with after hours wasted with searching for solution is this line of code: DynamicGI.UpdateEnvironment(); which I'm executing every 10 seconds or so in some of my Couroutines.
There's gotta be a better way but I don't know how.

This seems to be an (intentional?) change in specifically Unity 2023.2, as the 2023.1 docs include info on this, while 2023.2's docs does not. Checking through the 2023.2 release notes, there's mentions about how the "Auto Generate" feature was removed: "To check lightmaps while you’re editing, you can now select a Scene View Draw Mode and set Lighting Data to Preview"
